# How to get the key from a map associated with another list

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I need to create a map by associating List< String> with the key of the Map< String, List< String>> as follows.

````
 Input Map< String,List< String>>  - {"Fruit" -> ["apple","orange"], "Animal" -> ["cat","dog"]}

Input List< String> - {"apple","dog","xyzzy"}

output map as {"Fruit" -> "apple","Animal" -> "dog"} by discarding unmatching entries like "xyzzy" in this case" 


```
Map <String, String> outputMap = new HashMap<>();
Map <String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : inputMap.entrySet()) {
      entry.getValue().forEach(value -> tempMap.put(value, entry.getKey()));
   }    

 inputList.forEach(value ->
            {   
             if(tempMap.get(value)!=null)
             outputMap.put(tempMap.get(value),value); });
            }
````

The above code fails if the List contains multiple values belongs to same key because of duplication. For example

Input Map< String,List< String>>  - {"Fruit" -> ["apple","orange"], "Animal" -> ["cat","dog"]}

```
Input List< String> - {"apple","dog","cat"}
```

output map as `{"Fruit" -> "apple","Animal" -> "cat"} ("dog" is overriden by "cat")`

Is there a way to get output as

```
{"Fruit" -> "apple","Animal" -> "dog", "Animal" -> "cat"}
```

Is there a way to achieve this in a neater and precise way?

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in the map. So this question is invalid. How can you have two "Animal" s as keys here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your output type is `Map<String, List<String>>` you cannot get the output

```
{"Fruit" -> "apple","Animal" -> "dog", "Animal" -> "cat"}
```

(the `String` *"Animal"* is `key` and cannot be duplicated)

But, if you want filter the input map checking the containing lists you can do:

```
final Map<String, List<String>> inputMap = new HashMap<>();
inputMap.put("Fruit", asList("apple", "orange"));
inputMap.put("Animal", asList("cat", "dog"));

final List<String> list = asList("apple", "dog", "cat");

final Map<String, List<String>> outputMap = inputMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().stream().anyMatch(list::contains))
        .collect(toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue().stream().filter(list::contains).collect(toList())));

outputMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", k, v));
```

With output:

```
Fruit: [apple]
Animal: [cat, dog]
```

The double filtering traverse lists twice, this will be better or worse depending on how the input map is. Anyway, re-grouping is not required; if the inputs will match into a high percentage, you can do:

```
final Map<String, List<String>> outputMap = inputMap.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue().stream().filter(list::contains).collect(toList())))
        .filter(e -> !e.getValue().isEmpty())
        .collect(toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

A not directly related issue is that, to improve performance, the filter list is better to define as a `Set<String>`.